# Google play apps signing: The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I have generated a new keystore and export it to a PEPK file using android studio.
When I try to opt-in for apps signing in Google play console (Apps integrity) for an existing apps using the 'Export and upload a key from Android Studio' , I'm getting 'The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support' error message.  Please help....